# Compare in Array

Tags: java, javafx

I have a question regarding information in an array.

Right now I'm making a card game which needs a special type of card deck.
The deck contains **42 cards** no suits just a value of **1 - 21**. (2 cards of every value)
I need to check the players hand for 3 specific cards, the lowest - 1, 2 and 3.
if the hand contains - what is called 3 crappy cards the game will be over and the dealer gives you a new set of five cards.

In some way i need to go through **the hand (5 cards)** and check if it contains 3 of the crappy card. There is a total of 6 bad cards in the deck.

`private ArrayList<Card> playerHand = new ArrayList<Card>();` is what I'm using.

To get the value i use getters/setters -

```
for (int i = 0; i < playerHand.size(); i++) {
    int getValueOfCard = playerHand.get(i).getValue();
}
```

How do I solve this!? >.<

Comment: You need to a) differentiate between crappy/non-crappy cards and b) keep a counter of the crappy cards. The first suggest an `if` (maybe even a member in `Card`, the second a counter (also known as variables)... Maybe you should keep yourself to simpler examples while you learn the basics of programming and how to combine them.

Comment: You can use `if` statement to check if the current card from the `for` loop is `bad card` (`getValueOfCard`). If that's true, just increase the `total bad cards` counter.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "give me the code" question.

Answer (score 1):

```
public boolean isBadHand(PlayerHand playerHand){ 
 int badCards=0;  
 for (int i = 0; i < playerHand.size(); i++){

          int getValueOfCard = playerHand.get(i).getValue();
          if(getValueOfCard<=3){
          badCards++;
          }
       }
     if(badCards=>3){
         return true;
     }
     return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a metod checking cards:

```
public boolean isCrappyCard(Card c) {
    boolean isCrappy = c.getValue() <= 3 ? true : false;
    return isCrappy;
}
```

Then you will be able to do:

```
for (int i = 0; i < playerHand.size(); i++) {
    if (isCrappyCard(playerHand.get(i)) {
        if (count < 2) count ++
        else break;
    }
}
```

That will allow you to check if cards are crappy and it's number in hand